# Display int without basic library in c

Tags: c

because I need to display int without using simple library from C. I can only use this functions putch  and cputs.
I know it may seems a little weird but this is my task.
And functions atoi and itoa are welcome.
If you have some kind of idea please, share.

Comment: Use `itoa` then Use `cputs`.

Comment: What kind of format you expect? For example for N+ do you want the `+` in front of the number or just space or nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use itoa to make a string representation of your int; use puts to print that string.

Comment: I am doing something like this :
 char X[2];
 char Y[2];
 itoa(myintX, X, 10);
 itoa(myintY, Y, 10);

Comment: And how to display int value that is longer then 2, for example
numbers from 0 to 9 is displaying correctly but highter no

Comment: Use bigger `char` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of `itoa`:

```
/* strlen: return length of string s */
int strlen(char *s)
{
    int i;
    while (*s++) i++;
    return i;
}

/* reverse:  reverse string s in place */
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int c, i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}

/* itoa:  convert n to characters in s */
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign 0)
    s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 1024;
    char s[100];

    memset(s, 0, sizeof(s)-1);
    itoa(x, s);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        putchar(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: OP is allowed to use `itoa`; doesn't need to re-invent it.

Comment: @ScottHunter `itoa` is not a standard library function. True, it is implemented on most systems, but it is not standard.